# Pull out text before phrase - Regex R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am looking to extract the text appearing before a set of phrases using Regex in `R`.

Example phrases `c("PHRASE1", "PHRASE2", "PHRASE3")`.

Example text:

```
*NAME ALPHA PHRASE1 BLA BLA TEXT 81249
*NAME BETA PHRASE1 BLA BLA 81229
*NAME GAMMA PHRASE2 BLA BLA TEXT 85129
*NAME DELTA PHRASE3 BLA BLA 86129
*NAME EPSILON PHRASE2 BLA BLA 81729
```

I would like to pull out the following `c("NAME ALPHA", "NAME BETA", "NAME GAMMA")` and so on (ignoring the `*`).

Regex 101 link: https://regex101.com/r/Fzinr8/1

**Initial Attempt**

```
(!\*)q+(?=PHRASE1)
```

in `R`:

```
str_extract(x, "(!\*)q+(?=PHRASE1)")
```

Comment: What is `q` in your pattern? `!\*` matches a `!*` string, you do not have it anywhere in your strings. Mind you need to use double backslashes in regular string literals to define a literal backslash (a regex escape part)

Comment: sorry, I am very new to regex

Comment: But you know `q` matche a `q` char? What do you mean? Match any kind of chars as few as possible starting right after `*`? Or sequences of whitespace-separated words?

Comment: I am trying to pull all the characters before the start of the `PHRASE1`, so I wanted all the characters `q` so I put the `+`

Comment: Try this regex: `(?<=\*).*?(?=\s(?:PHRASE1|PHRASE2|PHRASE3))`

Comment: `str_match(x, "\\*(.*?)(?:\\s+(?:PHRASE1|PHRASE2|PHRASE3))")[,2]`

Comment: Not sure you want a base R solution, but this is something that might be useful for those who do not like to use additional libraries, so I included it to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex using a lookbehind and a lookahead:

```sh
str_extract(x, '(?<=\\*).*?(?=\\s(?:PHRASE1|PHRASE2|PHRASE3))');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fnS9Nn/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=\\*)`: Assert that we have a `*` at the previous position
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters (lazy match)
- `(?=\\s(?:PHRASE1|PHRASE2|PHRASE3))`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have a whitespace followed by `(?:PHRASE1|PHRASE2|PHRASE3)` ahead of the current position

Answer (score 1):

**A `stringr` solution**

You can use

```r
x<-c("*NAME ALPHA PHRASE1 BLA BLA TEXT 81249","*NAME BETA PHRASE1 BLA BLA 81229","*NAME GAMMA PHRASE2 BLA BLA TEXT 85129","*NAME DELTA PHRASE3 BLA BLA 86129","*NAME EPSILON PHRASE2 BLA BLA 81729")
library(stringr)
context <- c("PHRASE1", "PHRASE2", "PHRASE3")
str_match(x, paste0("\\*(.*?)\\s+(?:", paste(context, collapse="|"), ")"))[,2]
# => [1] "NAME ALPHA"   "NAME BETA"    "NAME GAMMA"   "NAME DELTA"   "NAME EPSILON"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e8u2lI/2).

*Details*

- `\*` - a `*` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (accessed after `str_match` with `[,2]`): any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+(?:PHRASE1|PHRASE2|PHRASE3)` - 1 or more whitespaces and one of the context strings.

**A base R solution**:

```r
x<-c("*NAME ALPHA PHRASE1 BLA BLA TEXT 81249","*NAME BETA PHRASE1 BLA BLA 81229","*NAME GAMMA PHRASE2 BLA BLA TEXT 85129","*NAME DELTA PHRASE3 BLA BLA 86129","*NAME EPSILON PHRASE2 BLA BLA 81729")
context <- c("PHRASE1", "PHRASE2", "PHRASE3")
pattern <- paste0("\\*\\K.*?(?=\\s+(?:", paste(context, collapse="|"), "))")
regmatches(x, regexpr(pattern, x, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "NAME ALPHA"   "NAME BETA"    "NAME GAMMA"   "NAME DELTA"   "NAME EPSILON"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/HM6jVl). Note a PCRE regex is required for this approach to work, thus `perl=TRUE` argument is obligatory.

The `\K` PCRE construct omits the text that was matched so far from the current match memory buffer. The `(?=...)` construct is a positive lookahead that matches a location in a string (that is why it is called a zero-width assertion) that is immediately followed with the lookahead pattern(s).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative with `strsplit()` and then removing trailing white spaces

**Code**

```
  sapply(str2, function(z){
    # remove * and whitespaces
    gsub("[*]|\\s+$", "", 
    # split by phrase and choose part of interest
    sapply(strsplit(str1, z)[grepl(z, str1)], "[[", 1))
   })
    
# $PHRASE1
# [1] "NAME ALPHA" "NAME BETA" 

# $PHRASE2
# [1] "NAME GAMMA"   "NAME EPSILON"

# $PHRASE3
# [1] "NAME DELTA"
```

**Data**

```
str1 <- c("*NAME ALPHA PHRASE1 BLA BLA TEXT 81249",
"*NAME BETA PHRASE1 BLA BLA 81229",
"*NAME GAMMA PHRASE2 BLA BLA TEXT 85129",
"*NAME DELTA PHRASE3 BLA BLA 86129",
"*NAME EPSILON PHRASE2 BLA BLA 81729")

str2 <- c("PHRASE1", "PHRASE2", "PHRASE3")
```